# Is it good to store chat messages in json field django?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

In my django app, I need a app for conversation between user and author for that I am planning to make a model as -

```
class AuthorContact(models.Model):
    messages = JSONField(default=dict)
    user = models.ForeginKey(User,related_name="contact_user",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeginKey(Author, related_name="contact_manager",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

what I am planning to store messages as -

```
{
'1':{'sender':'user','date':'02/12/2019','message':'Hi I read your book, it\'s amazing !'},
 '2':{'sender':'author','date':'0312/2019','message':'Thank you, it\'s my pleasure.}'
}
```

If message is `CharField` then I need to create object for every message with user and author.

I am doing this so I need not to create object for every message and its easy for db to find conversation between specific user and author.

**My questions are -**

Is it good practice ?

How much max size does PostgreSQL allow to store in this json field?

Is this trick beneficial, rather then creating object for every message and then searching for a specific chat ?

Is their any another better way?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that this solution is not ideal.

The max size of the `json` type in postgres is unlimited, but I don't think you want to take this direction with a large json dict dump. When this field grows, the time to retrieve it will only grow. Eventually you would have to filter something out on the API side somehow, otherwise you would have to send the entire text blob across the wire to your user.

Postgres is an excellent relational database, and in my oppinion you want to take advantege of this. Describe your objects to the database with the relations that they have.

I think you will generally always experience better speed and more flexibility when it comes to future development with a relational database. That is, in the cases where you know the structure of your data already or have no requirements to the speed with which it can be retrieved.

This is from the [postgres documentation on JSON types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html)

> **8.14.2. Designing JSON documents effectively**
>
> Representing data as JSON can be considerably more flexible than the
> traditional relational data
> model, which is compelling in environments where requirements are
> fluid. It is quite possible for both approaches to co-exist and
> complement each other within the same application. However, even for
> applications where maximal flexibility is desired, it is still
> recommended that JSON documents have a somewhat fixed structure. The
> structure is typically unenforced (though enforcing some business
> rules declaratively is possible), but having a predictable structure
> makes it easier to write queries that usefully summarize a set of
> "documents" (datums) in a table.
>
> JSON data is subject to the same concurrency-control considerations as
> any other data type when stored in a table. Although storing large
> documents is practicable, keep in mind that any update acquires a
> row-level lock on the whole row. Consider limiting JSON documents to a
> manageable size in order to decrease lock contention among updating
> transactions. Ideally, JSON documents should each represent an atomic
> datum that business rules dictate cannot reasonably be further
> subdivided into smaller datums that could be modified independently.

Also, when retrieving messages, you will be able to filter how many and how old messages that you want to retrieve. (WHERE created_time > 'yyyy-mm-dd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20) and such things. Some of the same effects could be achieved with the postgres JSON operators, but the speed would naturally never be comparable.

Basically, there is a long list of reasons that relational databases are superier to text blobs that I don't think you want to ignore.

**Edited from the lessons in the comments below from [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)**

Comment: But would you say that this type is superior to a normalized data struture? It is intended for storing JSON in, where you may not know the struture of the objects or perhaps have no requirements to speed of retrieval and search. I cannot see any reason for using it in this case, since he already knows the structure of the data that he wants to store.

Comment: But, I think it's great that you mention the type here - it may be useful to the OP. We may not know the whole case. And it's nice to know all options. +1